Why private field handling does not work in an expected way in JavaScript?
I think the next (simplified) code should be working:
class WfConfigurable {
    constructor(config) {
        this._init(config);
    }
    _init(config) {
        this.configure(config);
    }
    configure(config) {}
}

class WfStateful extends WfConfigurable {
    #saveSuspend = 0;
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
    }
    get saving() { return this.#saveSuspend == 0; }
    configure(config) {
        this.suspendSave();
        super.configure(config);
        this.continueSave();
    }
    suspendSave() {
        this.#saveSuspend++;
    }
    continueSave(force) {
        if (force) {
            this.#saveSuspend = 0;
        } else {
            this.#saveSuspend = Math.max(this.#saveSuspend - 1, 0);
        }
    }
}

class WfApp extends WfStateful {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
    }
}

const wfApp = new WfApp({});

But I have got the next error message:

TypeError: Cannot read private member #saveSuspend from an object whose class did not declare it
at WfApp.suspendSave ((index):24:13)
at WfApp.configure ((index):19:14)
at WfApp._init ((index):7:14)
at new WfConfigurable ((index):4:14)
at new WfStateful ((index):15:9)
at new WfApp ((index):37:9)
at (index):41:15

For example, this works well:
class A {
    #priv = 'hello';
    constructor() {
        console.log('A');
    }
    get priv() {
        return this.#priv;
    }
    set priv(p) {
        this.#priv = p;
    }
}

class B extends A {}

const b = new B();
b.priv += ' babe';
console.log(b.priv);

Writes out: "hello babe"

What’s the error stack?

Private properties are not inherited, so an instance of the subclass cannot access the properties even via code in the parent class.

@DanielA.White I don't think so it will help, but I have added the error stack.

What does configure actually do? Why not just do that in your constructor?

@Bergi In that simplified code, it does nothing. But in the real code, it will configure the object, and I want to make it callable separately, even after constructing time.

The error message "Cannot read private member #saveSuspend from an object whose class did not declare it" is slightly confusing. More accurate in this case would be "from an object where it is not (yet) initialised".
Private fields, and fields in general, are created on the instance (and initialised with the value defined in the class body) when the super() constructor returns. If that constructor is calling an overridden method (configure) before the initialisation is done, it will not be able to access the non-existing field. With private fields, it just throws an exception because the field doesn't exist, instead of returning undefined like a normal property.
The only solution is to never call an overrideable method from a constructor. This is true in any language. In your case, just get rid of the configure method altogether, it does not thing.
